# Google Cloud Platform - Ubuntu Pro - Quota format not supported in kernel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, linux-kernel, quota

I cannot get quota to work on Fresh copy of Ubuntu Pro

```
mount -o remount / quotacheck -avugm
    quotacheck: Scanning /dev/root [/] done
    quotacheck: Checked 19045 directories and 94713 files 
quotaon -avug
    quotaon: using //quota.group on /dev/root [/]: No such process
    quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel.
    quotaon: using //quota.use
    r on /dev/root [/]: No such process    
    quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel.
```

I have also installed sudo apt install linux-image-extra-virtual with no success finding the quota modules. find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -type f -name '*quota_v*.ko*'

uname -r = 5.4.0-1044-gcp

Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/844101/437769

Comment: I have done those steps before i posted the question.

Comment: The link I provided shows a number of steps to determine the problem. There are two primary items to review: a) the installed kernel modules. b) configuration setup. Your question lacks details in both areas.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get -y install quota quotatool
sudo apt install linux-image-extra-virtual
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-gcp
reboot
quotaoff -a
quotacheck -avugm
quotaon -avug
```

Answer (score 0):

Install required packages:

```
sudo apt-get -y install quota quotatool linux-image-extra-virtual  linux-modules-extra-gcp
```

Add *usrquota* option to mount options in `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Output:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults       0 1
```

Afterwards:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,usrquota,grpquota       0 1
```

Then proceed to remount the filesystem, as in this example we are using / :

```
sudo mount -o remount /
```

To examine the file system and build the required files for the quota utility, you will use the quotacheck command.
The command will create a file named aquota.user if it is not already in the system. Run the command below:

```
sudo quotacheck -ucm /
```

Verify aquota.user has been created under / folder:

```
sudo ls -ls /
```

Output:

```
 8 -rw-------   1 root root  7168 Jul  1 09:51 aquota.group
 8 -rw-------   1 root root  7168 Jul  1 09:51 aquota.user
```

Check if quota is enabled:

```
sudo quotaon -v /
```

Output:

```
/dev/root [/]: group quotas turned on
/dev/root [/]: user quotas turned on
```

Version of my reproduction:

```
$ uname -a
```

Linux ubuntupro 5.8.0-1035-gcp #37~20.04.1-Ubuntu